# Smart Card reader PCSC with multiple slots

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, winscard

I implemented a Card reader with CCID Protocol based on a microcontroller with three card slots.

In the description of the Protocol each team has the bytes of the numbers of slots for receiving the command.

The computer I use the app PCSC_Sample and SCardToolSet. The problem is that they only send requests to slot number 0.

How do you determine the number of card slots? Is it a certain parameter that in one of the answers sends Card READER to pcsc program as a parameter or does the program itself search for cards on the wizard (computer)? If the latter, then what program can you recommend for Windows 10?

Comment: OK, I found a command that is passed as slots (RDR_to_PC_NotifySlotChange). But the SOFTWARE on the computer side refers only to the card on the zero slot. What software can work with a multi-slot card reader?

Comment: Any example of a simple receipt RDR_to_PC_NotifySlotChange answer, connect, and send APDU. I've been surfing the Internet all day and I can't find anything worthwhile.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question instead of adding comments with additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All readers with several slots, I encountered (admittedly contact-based/contactless combinations, not several contact-based) are offering each slot under a separate friendly name. This also makes it easier for dumb applications to handle the scenario.

High security readers having a built-in security module in a second slot are unlikely to use PCSC.